# Why doesn't `auto &&` behave as a so-called "universal reference" when used as a lambda argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, rvalue

Why does the `&&` argument type in the following example not behave as a so-called "universal reference" even though it seems to be in a "deduced context", and instead is interpreted as an r-value:

```
auto main() -> int {    
    using MyFn = void (*)(int &);    
    MyFn special = [](auto && thing) {};  // compile error, deduced as int && rather than int&
    
    return 0;    
}
```

Whereas the following, which I expect to be equivalent, does work?

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &&){};

auto main() -> int {
    using MyFn = void (*)(int &);
    MyFn specialC = foo;
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect there's some esoteric detail with converting lambdas to function pointers that matters here, but so far I can't figure it out.

Comment: It should. What compiler?

Comment: Same behavior on both clang 10.0.0 and  and gcc 9.3.0

Answer (score 8):

Forwarding references are supported by a special deduction rule. The rule states that if we need to deduce `T` in order to make `T&&` identical to `U&`, then `T` is deduced as `U&` (so that `T&&` will be `U& (&&)`, which just collapses down to `U&`).

However, this special rule only applies under certain circumstances: when deducing function template template arguments based on the arguments to a function call ([[temp.deduct.call]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3)) (in the case that the argument is an lvalue of type `U`, which you can imagine as having the type "`U&`"), when taking the address of a function template, and when matching a function template specialization declaration against a primary template declaration ([[temp.deduct.type]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#type-10)).

Your case is none of the above, but is instead a separate case of deducing template arguments for a conversion function template ([[temp.deduct.conv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.conv)), which doesn't have the special rule for forwarding references.

Another example where the forwarding reference deduction rules don't apply is the following, which will therefore not compile:

```
template <class T>
void foo(void(*)(T&&)) {}

void bar(int&) {}

int main() {
    foo(bar);
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure it needs a special rule. It's just rewriting to calling a function template that takes a function type as a parameter. Which I think [should work](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#10) even though [nobody accepts it](https://godbolt.org/z/cjaMMdbEq)

Answer (score 0):

In lambda parameters, `auto` by itself gives universal type deduction.  So this does what you want:

```
MyFn special = [](auto thing) {};
```

Demo using a non-copyable type to prove it's not passing by value: https://godbolt.org/z/5vfWc6c8x

Comment: This could be easily misunderstood. `auto` in the lambda parameter behaves exactly as `T` in a function template with template parameter `T`. It always deduces the type to a non-reference in a call expression. However deduction of the template arguments of a conversion function template works differently as explained in the other answer. I am not sure what the demo is supposed to show. Obviously calling a function pointer with `S&&` as parameter isn't pass-by-value.